# How to optimize cpu consumption in d3js responsive bar chart when browser resizes

Tags: javascript, browser

I wrote some of code to do responsive bar chart, but cpu consumption gets high when i resize the browser.
How can i optimize the code to make it less hard to cpu?

i've removed some float variables

```
window.onload = window.onresize = function()
{
    ancho = d3.select(svg).node()._groups[0][0].clientWidth;
    largo = d3.select(svg).node()._groups[0][0].clientHeight;

    if((rango[0]*multiplicador) > largo)
    {
        multiplicador = multiplicador/2;
        console.log(multiplicador+' > '+largo);
    }
    else
    {
        if((rango[0]*multiplicador) < largo-50)
        {
            multiplicador = multiplicador+multiplicador/2;
            console.log(multiplicador+' > '+largo);
        }
    }

    svg.selectAll('rect').remove();
    svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(datos)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('fill','blue')
    .attr('stroke','red')
    .attr('x',          function(data, index){return ((ancho/(datos.length))*index) + espaciado;})
    .attr('y',          function(data, index){return (largo)-(data*multiplicador);})
    .attr('width',      function(data, index){return (ancho/datos.length)-espaciado;})
    .attr('height',     function(data, index){return data*multiplicador;});
}
```

it works without errors

Comment: Consider using throttling/debouncing. See [this article](http://bencentra.com/code/2015/02/27/optimizing-window-resize.html)

Comment: thanks!!!, that's just what i needed. I'm choosing that article as answer

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Yaelet, reading this [article](http://bencentra.com/code/2015/02/27/optimizing-window-resize.html) i found how minimize cpu consumption when resizing the browser:

**1. Throttling:**
 the chart doesn't resizes at every browser resizing events, with timeout i can set how miliseconds i want to skip.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    // only run if we're not throttled
  if (!throttled) {
    // actual callback action
    getDimensions();
    // we're throttled!
    throttled = true;
    // set a timeout to un-throttle
    setTimeout(function() {
      throttled = false;
    }, delay);
  }  
});
```

**2. Debouncing:**
The chart only resizes when window resizing finishes.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    // clear the timeout
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  // start timing for event "completion"
  timeout = setTimeout(getDimensions, delay);
});
```

finally, i would appreciate to read some other tips to reduce cpu impact when window is resizing.