# How to truncate String with Ellipsis in svg

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, d3.js

I am using the d3 library to create Bar Charts. The values on the axes are strings (for example, some names). I have the ability to drag the axis to change the size of the graphs. Resizing the graph causes a recalculation of the line that fit in the previous empty space. Since I'm using d3 (that's working with svg), I can't use the css property to add '...' if the string doesn't fit, I have to do it manually. The function I am using is given below:

```js
protected truncateLabel(
  truncatedLabel: Selection<SVGTextElement, unknown, null, undefined>,
  textToFit: string,
  freeSpacePx: number,
) {
  truncatedLabel.node().textContent = textToFit;

  const averageWidthOfCharInPx = truncatedLabel.node().textLength.baseVal.value / textToFit.length;

  if (truncatedLabel.node().textLength.baseVal.value <= freeSpacePx){
    return truncatedLabel;
  }

  const numberOfCharsThatWillFit = freeSpacePx / averageWidthOfCharInPx;

  truncatedLabel.node().textContent = textToFit.slice(0, numberOfCharsThatWillFit - 2) + '...';
  return truncatedLabel;
}
```

Everything works well if there are few bars, but if there are many bars, resizing starts to slow down a lot because of this function.
Is there a better way to check if a string fits and add '...'?
Or any way to optimize my function?

Comment: Instead of truncating, what about rotating your labels so that they are less affected by resizing? E.g. see https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_basic.html

Comment: @stuwilmur Thanks for your answer! But due to specifics of the task, i can not refuse my approach with truncating.

Comment: Could you throttle or debounce the chart resize events? E.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57036301/how-to-optimize-cpu-consumption-in-d3js-responsive-bar-chart-when-browser-resize